# how to fix 'fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, zip

I'm writing a python application to unzip zip archive files but am getting an error.

I've tried renaming the file and removing parts of the script that are unnecessary.

My script is :

```
import zipfile
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as mgb
import tkinter.filedialog as tkfd

OutputPath = ""
ZIPFile = ""

root = tk.Tk()

def OpenFile() :
    global ZIPFile
    global OutputPath
    ZIPFile = tkfd.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file")
    if OutputPath != "" and ZIPFile != "" : ZipBut.state(["!disabled"])


def OutputFile() :
    global OutputPath
    global ZIPFile
    OutputPath = tkfd.askdirectory(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file")
    if OutputPath != "" and ZIPFile != "" : ZipBut.state(["!disabled"])

def unzip() :
    global ZIPFile
    global OutputPath

    with zipfile.ZipFile(ZIPFile) as File :
        File.extractall(path = OutputPath)

CommandBar = ttk.Frame(root)
CommandBar.pack()

ttk.Button(CommandBar, text = "open", command = OpenFile).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
ttk.Button(CommandBar, text = "output", command = OutputFile).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
ZipBut = ttk.Button(CommandBar, text = "unzip", command = unzip)
ZipBut.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
ZipBut.state(["disabled"])

root.mainloop()
```

Im Expecting the file to unzip into a folder of choice however get a Exception

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1558, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/ZIP/main.pyw", line 29, in unzip
    with zipfile.ZipFile(ZIPFile) as File :
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1111, in _RealGetContents
    fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: have you verified that `ZIPFile` and `OutputPath` are what you assume they are when you try to call `ZipFile`?

Comment: They should just be file locations as they are never changed from that and the code explicitly states that by disabling the unzip function until the variables are set through the file dialog

Comment: What they should be and what they actually are can sometimes be two different things. One of the very first steps in debugging is to verify your assumptions about data.

Comment: after further testing it appears to be broken when selecting zip files with changed file extensions. such as opening test.zip in notepad and saving as test.txt